# In what circumstances would a fileReferenceURL be useful

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

[moveItemAtURL:toURL:error](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1414750-moveitematurl)

The new location for the item in srcURL. **The URL in this parameter must not be a file reference URL** and must include the name of the file or directory in its new location. This parameter must not be nil.

Given the above restriction, in what circumstances would a fileReferenceURL be useful?

Comment: Read apple docs, they are quiet clear : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1408631-filereferenceurl

Comment: Docs will give you the usage not "Why would I use a file reference URL?" answer. You use your own mind to choose which is best for the particular scenario based on the requirement and result.

Comment: So why did you suggest I read the docs?

Comment: To clear your basics, so that you will be able to distinguish "what to use ?", "why to use ?" and "when to use ?" by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your time. @SharadChauhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fileURL` is a file's path at which file is present and to access it we need to fetch that file using its `fileURL`.

On the other hand `fileReferenceURL` points to the file directly rather than its location. So if file is moved the `fileURL` will change with that so we need to keep checking for `fileURL` if we want to access it, but `fileReferenceURL` will stay the same.

According to doc about `fileReferenceURL`:

> A file reference URL's path should never be persistently stored, because it is not valid across system restarts or remounts of volumes

So basically to move a file you need a path (fileURL) and not the reference of the file (fileReferenceURL).

Comment: I am not sure about that, according to what I have read yes this returns a reference URL and it is read only.